# Understanding a question in algebra

Tags: notation

> Does the equality $\lfloor nx \rfloor = n\lfloor x \rfloor$ hold for
> the integers $n\ge 2$?

What does this sign "$\lfloor$" and " $\rfloor$" sign mean in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: it is the ["floor function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

Comment: No, just take $x = 1/n$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of floor symbols in $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2 \lfloor x \rfloor - x + 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487568/meaning-of-floor-symbols-in-fx-dfrac12-lfloor-x-rfloor-x-1)

Answer (score 1):

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the largest integer **not more than** $x$, where $x$ is any real number. For example, $\lfloor 13 \rfloor=13$, $\lfloor 22.2 \rfloor=22$ and $\lfloor -\pi \rfloor=-4$.

Now, to answer your original question, let $x=\dfrac{1}{n}$. Then, $\lfloor nx \rfloor=\lfloor 1 \rfloor=1$, but $n\lfloor x \rfloor=n\cdot 0=0$. Hence, the statement does not hold.